# Passing parameters to a function using loop

Tags: function, powershell, for-loop, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a function

```
Function newFunction($1, $2, $3)
{
    $1 + $2 + $3
}
```

and

```
Param (
    [string]$intro= 'My Name is ',
    [string]$name= 'Mark. ',
    [string]$greeting= 'Hello'
    )
```

it can be ran with.
    newFunction $intro $name $greeting

resulting in.
    My Name is Mark. Hello

What I would like to do is some way of storing multiple Params and passing them to the function (this syntax in this next part might be wrong but hopefully you get the point.

```
Param ({
    [string]$intro= 'My Name is ',
    [string]$name= 'Mark. ',
    [string]$greeting= 'Hello'
    }{
    [string]$intro= 'My Name is ',
    [string]$name= 'not Mark. ',
    [string]$greeting= 'Howdy!'
    }
```

How could i get a for loop to pass each of these to print
    My Name is Mark. Hello
    My Name is Not Mark. Howdy!

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a complete function definition:

```
function New-Greeting
{
    param(
        [string]$Intro = "My name is:",
        [string]$Name = "Mark",
        [string]$Greeting = "Hello!"
    )

    return "$Greeting $Intro $Name"
}
```

You then need to pass the parameter arguments to the function from the calling scope, not inside the function definition.

For example with variable `Name` parameter values:

```
$Names = "Mark","John","Bobby"
foreach($Name in $Names){
    New-Greeting -Name $Name
}
```

will return:

```
Hello! My name is: Mark
Hello! My name is: John
Hello! My name is: Bobby
```

---

If you want multiple sets of variable arguments, consider storing them in hashtables and then splat them, like so:

```
# Define array of hashtables
$GreetingArguments = @(
    @{
        Intro = "They call me"
        Name = "Mark"
        Greeting = "Howdy!"
    },@{
        Name = "John"
        Greeting = "Good morning!"
    },@{
        Intro = "I go by: "
        Name = "Bobby"
    }
)

foreach($Greeting in $GreetingArguments){
    # "splat" the individual hashtables from the array
    New-Greeting @Greeting
}
```

resulting in:

```
Howdy! They call me Mark
Good morning! My name is: John
Hello! I go by: Bobby
```

As you can see, `New-Greeting` defaults to the string defined in the `param()` block whenever you *don't* pass an argument